# stop blur event from triggering as a result of keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the event 'keydown' is detected, the event 'blur' is also automatically triggered. How can I prevent the 'blur' event on the element if 'keydown' event is triggered?
Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CxFaq/) and the code:
HTML:

```
<div id="delegatee">
    <span id="ctrl" contenteditable="true"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#ctrl {
    width:100px;
    height:50x;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function saveOrDelete() {
    $("#ctrl").attr('contentEditable', false);    
    alert('Triggered'); // alerts 2 times
}
$("#delegatee").on('keydown blur', '#ctrl', saveOrDelete)
```

Please note, that this solution doesn't work:

```
function saveOrDelete() {
    $("#delegatee").off('keydown blur', '#ctrl', saveOrDelete)
    $("#ctrl").attr('contentEditable', false);    
    alert('Trigger');
    $("#delegatee").on('keydown blur', '#ctrl', saveOrDelete)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is causing this behavior:

`$("#ctrl").attr('contentEditable', false);`

As soon as the span is no longer `contentEditable` it will lose focus and hence `blur` is raised.

You will have to re-think your logic.

*Edit (After your comment):*

In order to trap the `blur` which immediately follows a `keydown` because of the above reason, you may change your logic to first check if the span is editable and then take action based on that.

e.g.

```
var mode = $("#ctrl").prop('contentEditable');
if (mode == 'true') { 
    $("#ctrl").prop('contentEditable', false);
    // your other processes here
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Check the update on your fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/CxFaq/1/**

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, thank :). My question is how can I get around that behavior?