# AngularJS - prevent ng-keydown trigger ng-blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with angularJS and I need a way to stop the execution of ng-blur when ng-keydown is executed, since ng-keydown at some point makes the element lose the focus.

The HTML is:

```
<div contenteditable ng-show="contentEditableSupport" ng-init="oldName = ''" ng-focus="oldName = userGroup.name" ng-model="userGroup.name" strip-br="true"
  ng-blur="editName(userGroup, oldName)" ng-keydown="$event.keyCode === 13 && editName(userGroup, oldName)">{{userGroup.name}}</div>
```

The angular attribute directive is:

```
angular.module("mainApp").directive('contenteditable', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
          //Code from: http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/editing-text-in-place-using-html5-content-editable.html
          function read() {
              ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
          }

          ngModel.$render = function () {
              element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || "");
          };

          element.bind("blur keyup change", function () {
              scope.$apply(read);
          });

      }
  };
});
```

If I edit the text in the element and click elsewhere the `editName` method is called once, but if I edit it and press enter the method is called twice. I tried to consume `$event.stopPropagation` and similar with no results.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583550/stop-blur-event-from-trigerring-as-a-result-of-keypress

Comment: What does `editName` do?

Comment: @JonSenchyna it runs some checks (like empty name or same name) and then calls a method on the backend to update to entity.

Comment: Normally, pressing `enter` in an editable div simply inserts a `newline` and keeps it in "edit-mode".  Is there code in `editName` that is causing it to lose focus?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue appears to lie in whatever code is triggering the div to lose focus when the user types `enter`.

You should be able to fix it by replacing `&& editName(...)` in your `ng-keydown` handler with code that simply causes the control to lose focus.  It will then delegate calling `editName(...)` to the `ng-blur` handler when you press `enter`, preventing the duplicate calls.

Comment: Right, a coworker told me the same. I'm in the search on how to make the element lose the focus, somewhitng like this is not working:              $scope.doBlur = function () {
                var activeElement = $document[0].activeElement;

                if (activeElement) {
                    activeElement.blur();
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

In the directive 'contentEditable' i added:

```
          element.bind("blur keydown", function ($event) {
              if ($event.which == 13) {
                  element[0].blur();
              }
          });
```

And i deleted the ng-keydown attribute in the div tag.

Works like a charm