# How to make this error msg not print twice? (how to make ng-keypress not trigger ng-blur)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, coffeescript

Problem: The error message generated by `symc_invalid_pin_name` (having invalid character such as /, >, and so on) is printed twice.

My investigation: Since the error message will only be printed once when the textbox loses focus by just clicking mouse somewhere else, but printed twice when I hit enter when focusing on the textbox, I assume it's because ng-keypress triggers ng-blur. When I was looking for solution I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781264/angularjs-prevent-ng-keydown-trigger-ng-blur). But I don't think the answer helped much since the first answer just provided the concept but not the solution, the second answer was using jQuery instead of AngularJS (I might be wrong because I am new to web developement). Also I want to make sure what is causing the problem is the ng-blur being triggered by ng-keypress.

HTML:

```
<td id="symbol-pin-name" class="listings-pin-name" ng-click="selectPin(pin)" ng-dblclick="editPinName($event, pin)" ng-class="getUserDefinedNameClass(pin)">
    <div>
      <span ng-click="editPinName($event, pin)"><svg class="icon icon-pencil"><use xlink:href="#icon-pencil"></use></svg></span>
      <span ng-bind="pin.name" ng-show="changedPin.id != pin.id">A26</span>
      <input maxlength="40" type="text" id="edit-pin-name-text-{{pin.id}}" ng-model="editedPinNames[pin.id]" ng-show="changedPin.id == pin.id" ng-blur="pinNameEditBlur($event, pin)" ng-keydown="pinNameChanged($event, pin)" ng-cloak>
    </div>
  </td>
```

CoffeeScript:

```
$scope.pinNameChanged = (e, p) ->
id = p.id
switch e.keyCode
  when 13
    illegalChars = new RegExp("[$\'\"\\\\<>`\\s]")
    pinToBeChanged = pin for pin in $rootScope.pins when pin.id is id
    if illegalChars.test($scope.editedPinNames[id].trim())
      $rootScope.$emit("GenericError", i18n.symc_invalid_pin_name)
      $scope.changedPin.id = ""
    else
      if $scope.editedPinNames[id].trim() is ""
        matchedPin = $rootScope.masterTerminals.filter ((t) -> t.jedecName is p.jedecName)[0]
        if matchedPin?
          $scope.editedPinNames[id] = if matchedPin.label? then matchedPin.label else ""
        else
          $scope.editedPinNames[id] = ""
      else
        $scope.editedPinNames[id] = $scope.editedPinNames[id].trim()
      $rootScope.$emit('PinPropertyUpdate', [id], name: $scope.editedPinNames[id])
      $rootScope.updateStandardSvg()
      $rootScope.$emit('Redraw')
      $scope.changedPin.id = ""
  when 27
    cancelPinNameEdit()

$scope.pinNameEditBlur = (e, p) -> $scope.pinNameChanged({keyCode: 13}, p)
```

I am using AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
ng-blur="$event.preventDefault()"
```

or even for yours pinNameChanged($event, pin) add

```
$event.preventDefault() or $event.stopPropagation()
```

Comment: But by using this clicking outside of the textbox won't make the textbox lose focus right? So though hit enter won't make the error message printed twice, clicking outside of the textbox will make the error message print 0 time instead of once.